# Excel - Simple formula to replace specific letters with specific numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dificulty creating a formula which will generate specific numbers from specifis letters in next row.
I would like to have the word KLAGENFURT represented in numbers 1234567890 and when the letters are together in one cell RGK for example the next cell would write them as 941.
Is it even possible?

Thank you!

Example data, which I "translated" manually
[image]

The left column has data in letters, the right column has them transcribed in numbers and that is the result I would love to have using formula.
Sorry for my complicated explanations, I am not native english speaker...

Comment: As @Bruce has said,  you could use `SUBSTITUTE`, or maybe just `=IF(A1="KLAGENFURT",1234567890,"")`  I can see, I think, that you mean `K=1`,`L=2`, `A=3` and so on.  Could you update your question with what VBA code or Excel formula you have tried so far?  Possibly some kind of lookup table and something that splits the word into separate letters?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function xlate(s As String) As String
    Dim L As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim ch As String

    letters = Array("A", "G", "N", "L", "E", "F", "K", "U", "R", "T")
    numbers = Array("3", "4", "6", "2", "5", "7", "1", "8", "9", "0")

    L = Len(s)
    For i = 1 To L
        ch = Mid(s, i, 1)
        For j = 0 To 9
            If ch = letters(j) Then xlate = xlate & numbers(j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it by formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MOD(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1),"klagenfurt"),10)*
10^(LEN(A1)-ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)))))
```

[image]